# ¿Por qué la expresión "ser pan comido" significa fácil?

Tags: etimología, historia, locuciones

Es común decir que algo es "pan comido" para indicar que es muy fácil. Por ejemplo:

> Ese trabajo no es nada complicado. Será pan comido para ti.

¿De dónde viene esta expresión? ¿Está su origen relacionado con el "to be a piece of cake" del inglés?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya en el siglo XIV existía un dicho que era "el pan comido, la compañía deshecha":

> *La conpañía de los buenos es de buscar, la qual es caritativa e deleytosa, entre los quales deve aver verdat e non ser conpañeros de mesa que digan: el pan comido, la conpañía desfecha.*
>
> Anónimo, "Tratado de la Comunidad (Biblioteca de El Escorial MS. &-II-8)", c 1370 (España).

El *Diccionario de Autoridades* define este dicho como:

> Refr. que se dice por los ingratos, que despues de haber recibido el beneficio, se olvidan dél, y no hacen caso, y se apartan de aquel de quien le recibieron.

Es decir, que es muy cómodo y de ingratos establecer un trato, recibir tu favor (el pan comido) y luego no cumplir con tu parte. Este refrán fue popular durante el siglo XVII, apareciendo incluso en el Quijote por boca de Sancho: "No se dirá por mí, señor mío, el pan comido, y la compañía deshecha."

No encuentro casos del refrán en el siglo XVIII, pero a partir del XIX empiezan a aparecer casos en la hemeroteca de la primera parte del refrán, haciendo alusión a la parte fácil del trato: el pan comido.

> *Visto esto, y unido á la anterior noticia de* La Opinione, *parece que en efecto todo género de ocupacion debía suspenderse, como tambien toda especie de seguridad absoluta de que la anexion es pan comido.*
>
> El Pensamiento español (Madrid. 1860). 29/3/1860, página 1.

De ahí surgió la idea de que algo que es "pan comido" es algo fácil de conseguir.

Comment: Sí, tienes razón.  Voy a borrar y te veo ahí en un par de días.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a [esta entrada de judaísmovirtual](http://www.judaismovirtual.com/curiosidades/x.pancomido.php) es una expresión que tiene su origen en la Torá. Según la web Bamidbar 14: 5 versa con respecto al momento posterior al regreso de los espías que fueron a explorar la tierra de Israel e informaron que no es propicia para ser conquistada.

> *"Moshé y Aharón cayeron sobre sus rostros delante de toda la congregación de Israel. Ieoshúa bin Nun y Kaleb ben Iefuné rasgaron sus ropas y dijeron al pueblo: La tierra que estuvimos en ella para explorarla es muy buena. Si es la voluntad deHashem [sic] propicia hacia nosotros, nos traerá a esa tierra y nos la dará. Es una tierra que mana leche y miel. Pero contra Hashem no se revelen, y no teman al pueblo de la tierra pues **ellos son nuestro pan**"*
>
> **Esta expresión "son nuestro pan" significa - explica Rashi - "Los comeremos como pan".**
>
> O sea que es la tan conocida frase: "Son pan comido", que tanto utilizamos cuando nos referimos a nuestros rivales, en algún deporte, juego de salón, o lo que sea.

[Este otro enlace de la misma web](http://www.judaismovirtual.com/efraim/vaietze.php) lo explica un poco mejor con

> Según Rashi esta interpretación era una manera en que Hashem le dice a Yakov que **la tierra será fácil de conquistar para su descendencia**.
>
> En otras palabras, podemos tomar la explicación midrashica simplemente como una expresión literaria, así como decir ‘es pan comido’

Como sabemos la legua española ha sufrido influencia de muchas culturas. La cultura judaica estuvo presente en España por muchos años, y desde luego su influencia no terminó con [la expulsión de los judíos en 1492 por parte de los Reyes Católicos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expulsi%C3%B3n_de_los_jud%C3%ADos_de_Espa%C3%B1a). Por tanto, no sería descabellado asumir que el origen de esta expresión en la lengua castellana viene de la cultura judaica.

La expresión no parece estar relacionada con "[to be a piece of cake](http://www.knowyourphrase.com/phrase-meanings/Piece-Of-Cake.html)" ya que al parecer el origen de esta frase es de 1930.

> this saying goes back to at least the 1930s. The term was used with its figurative meaning by an American poet named Ogden Nash, who wrote a book called Primrose Path in 1936. There's a part from it that reads:
>
> > "Her picture's in the papers now, And life's a piece of cake."

Comment: Dos explicaciones geniales. Lástima poder marcar solo una como respuesta... Gracias por incluir la explicación de "piece of cake". Pensé que estaban relacionados por ser comida ambos.