# ¿Por qué algo fácil "está chupado"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

La pregunta sobre la expresión «pan comido»: [¿Por qué la expresión "ser pan comido" significa fácil?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22762/14069) me ha hecho pensar en otra expresión para decir que algo es fácil: *está chupado*.

El DLE dice de *chupado*:

> **[chupado, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=94LLQSz)**
>
> *Del part. de chupar.*
>
> **1.** adj. coloq. Muy flaco y extenuado.
>
> **2.** adj. coloq. Muy fácil.

No hay nada en el verbo *[chupar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=94gRaCx)* de lo que se pueda deducir ese significado, al menos yo no soy capaz de encontrarlo.

¿De donde viene entonces decir que algo está chupado cuando algo es fácil?

Answer (score 3):

Pues parece una expresión de reciente cuño. No encuentro casos en el CORDE, y en el CREA el primero parece ser este:

> *Pisando fuerte, diciéndome una y otra vez que no puede fallar, que está chupado, recorro los escasos metros que me separan de la puerta del Banco.*
>
> Carlos Pérez Merinero, "Días de guardar", 1981 (España).

Y en el DLE aparece por primera vez en la edición de 1983 del *Diccionario manual ilustrado de la lengua española", aportando además un dato que nos revela su origen:

> **chupado, da.** || fig. vulg. Se dice entre estudiantes de las preguntas, lecciones, etc., muy fáciles.

Esto coincide con lo que yo recuerdo que fueron mis primeros usos de la expresión. Ahora bien, ¿cómo se generó en ámbitos escolares y/o universitarios esta expresión? Mucho me temo que ignoro la respuesta, aunque es posible que provenga de algún símil que haga alusión a alguna tarea extremadamente fácil, como chupar un caramelo, o chuparse el dedo que, aunque esto hace alusión a otro dicho diferente, no deja de ser lo primero que aprender a hacer un niño, y es por tanto una tarea fácil.

Answer (score 2):

Entre 1972 y 1974 Joe Rígoli, un cómico y actor argentino afincado por entonces en España, aparecía en un programa los domingos llamado 'Tarde para todos'. En él había un concurso y siempre que se hacia la pregunta o lo que tenían que hacer los concursantes decía: "¡Esto está chupado!" haciendo una mueca muy característica. Esa fue la primera vez que oí esa expresión que se puso inmediatamente de moda por todo el país, la frase y la mueca.